# C How can I acces struct members of a struct that is part of a struct array in another struct?

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, struct

If I have the 3 following structs:

```
/*Structures*/
typedef struct team
{
    char* name;
    int playedGames;
    int score;
}team;

typedef struct matchday
{
    char* date;
    team team1;
    team team2;
    team winner; 
    bool isPlayed;
}matchday;

typedef struct sportSeason
{
    matchday *calendar;
    team *ranking;
    int totalMatches;
    int matchesPlayed;
    int remainingMatches;
}sportSeason;
```

And the following code:

```
sportSeason *ptr = malloc(sizeof(sportSeason));
```

**How can I edit/acces the members of team or matchday arrays in the structure?**

For example

```
ptr->ranking[0]->name = "Team A";
```

doesn't work.

Kind regards,
AggonyAchilles

full code (for what it's worth):

```
#define _CRTDDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#define MAX_BUFFER_SIZE 81
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

/*Structures*/
typedef struct team
{
    char* name;
    int playedGames;
    int score;
}team;

typedef struct matchday
{
    char* date;
    team team1;
    team team2;
    team winner; 
    bool isPlayed;
}matchday;

typedef struct sportSeason
{
    matchday *calendar;
    team *ranking;
    int totalMatches;
    int matchesPlayed;
    int remainingMatches;
}sportSeason;

/*Function prototypes*/
void initSeason(sportSeason *obj, int n);
void newTeam(team **obj, int *n);
void bufferCheck(char string[]);

int main(void)
{
    char buffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
    int totalMatches, teams;
    sportSeason *footbalSeason = NULL;

    //Memory allocation
    footbalSeason = malloc(sizeof(sportSeason));

    printf("Welcome to a new season: \n");
    printf("Please enter the following information before registering the teams: \n");
    printf("How many teams are participating: \n");
    fgets(buffer, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE, stdin);
    teams = atoi(buffer);

    initSeason(footbalSeason, teams);


    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
    return 0;
}

void initSeason(sportSeason *obj, int n)
{
    char buffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];

    sportSeason *temp = obj;

    temp->totalMatches = (((n + 1) * n) / 2);
    temp->matchesPlayed = 0;
    temp->remainingMatches = 0;

    printf("Register teams: \n");

    /*Passing the adres of the pointer to the first element of the rank 
      array (team *) */
    newTeam(&(temp->ranking), &n);

}

void newTeam(team **obj, int *n)
{
    char buffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];

    //Allocate memory for all the teams
    obj = malloc((*n) * sizeof(team));

    if (obj == NULL)
    {
        printf("Memory reallocation failed");
    }

    else
    {
        //Add information to struct members
        for (int i = 0; i < (*n); ++i)
        {
            obj[i]->playedGames = 0;
            obj[i]->score = 0;

            printf("\nEnter the team name: ");
            fgets(buffer, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE, stdin);
            bufferCheck(buffer);

            strcpy(obj[i]->name, buffer);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no array in your code, just pointers. They are not the same type. And "doesn't work" is not a **specific** problem statement! Maybe you start reaqding a good C book? (or get a new one)

Comment: Hey @Olaf, thanks for you awnser.  It is indeed not, I highlighted my problem statement. And yes, they're pointers, you are right. I must've been confused.

Comment: the problem is not an array approach since all arrays are basicly pointers (not vice versa though) the problem lies with "obj = malloc((*n) * sizeof(team));
" it's a p2p treated as normal pointer

Comment: @LiorA: "... all arrays are basicly pointers" - Don't state such nonsense! Arrays are **not** pointers!

Comment: @olaf , well they are chunk of type(something) over your stack, pointer is an adress of something, i can treat array as pointer: int a[4];  *(a+2) = 8; completely valid. why? if a is not actually points to the start of that chunk of allocated memory over your stack rather than heap(where dynamicly allocated memory is laying), so that's why i wrote   "all arrays are basicly pointers (not vice versa though)" <-not vice versa means exactly what you read. pointers are NOT arrays, arrays are at least their variable name acts and treated as such to be continued...

Comment: int a[5] = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
 cout << a << "\n" <<  //will print the address of the first "cell" 
  *a << "\n" <<  //will print the first element
  *(a + 3) << "\n";   more over, c conventions to send arrays to functions are eg. void f(int arr[])  which can easily replaced by void f(int *arr) i hope now you see what did i meant when i wrote that statement.

Comment: @LiorA: FDor a starter, the C standard does not mandate using a stack and there are implementations which don't. And how an array is **internally** handled by an application, is not relevant here.

Comment: what's FDor? ,  i find that important and maybe it's subjective but defenetly not "nonsense" as you've stated before. as far as i view it : int a[5] = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
 int * const p = a;  makes p and a equivalent or at least if you care to be so precise very similar,in that case please emphesize the big difference that makes p and a, not synanmous and different in such a way that it's "nonsense" cause with all honesty i don't see the fine point that makes you object my pov on that matter, i would actually like to hear an answer for that(i don't dig in my pos but try to clarify it)

Comment: @LiorA: A typo, smartass. `sizeof(a) != sizeof(p)` It is nonsense to tell beginners that an array is a pointer in C. Read about automiatic conversion (aka "decaying").

Comment: @Olaf, regarding array decaying thank you! and regarding Fdor: not a smartass, i really thought you Fdor might have a meaning (abbreviative to some concept i don't know or something)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there're issues with allocation. 
when you send pointer to pointer you basicly gives the address of that pointer
means if you sent:

```
  newTeam(&(temp->ranking), &n);
```

to actually allocate it you'll need:
in newTeam to do:

```
  void newTeam(team **obj, int *n)
  {
    //blahblah
    (*obj) = (team*) malloc(sizeof(team)* (*n));
```

why? a) p2p is the address of that pointer means to actually refer to pointer we need *obj , remember that malloc returns void* it's safer this way.
if we'll simplify it all to a code in main it will be something like:

```
int main(){
 sportSeason *ptr = (sportSeason*)malloc(sizeof(sportSeason));
 ptr->totalMatches = ptr->remainingMatches = ptr->remainingMatches = 0;
 ptr->calendar = (matchday*)malloc(4*sizeof(matchday));
 ptr->calendar[0].date = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 4);
 strcpy_s(ptr->calendar[0].date,4,"hi");
 printf("%s", ptr->calendar[0].date);
 //...
```

it's more than correct to use functions for those actions (really nice that you implemented it in a modular fashion!

a code eg. would be:

```
  int main(void)
   {
      char buffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
      int teams;
      sportSeason *footbalSeason = NULL;

      //Memory allocation
      footbalSeason = (sportSeason*)malloc(sizeof(sportSeason));

      printf("Welcome to a new season: \n");
      printf("Please enter the following information before registering the teams: \n");
      printf("How many teams are participating: \n");
      fgets(buffer, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE, stdin);
      teams = atoi(buffer);

      initSeason(footbalSeason, teams);
```

...
       void initSeason(sportSeason *obj, int n)
       {
           char buffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];

```
       sportSeason *temp = obj; //bit unnessery to have temp but w/e

       temp->totalMatches = (((n + 1) * n) / 2);
       temp->matchesPlayed = 0;
       temp->remainingMatches = 0;

       printf("Register teams: \n");

       /*Passing the adres of the pointer to the first element of the rank
      array (team *)<-INCORRECT you pass the address to the pointer it's basicly nothing more - you allocate it */
      newTeam(&(temp->ranking), &n);
      printf("%d\n",temp->ranking[0].playedGames); //will print it just fine

   }

   void newTeam(team **obj, int *n)
   {
      *obj = (team*)malloc(sizeof(team)*(*n));
     obj[0]->playedGames = 0; //for eg.

   }
```

btw w.e u do when you allocate memory you must actually free it don't be lazy and use the _crt directive since it's applying only in debug mode and not all compilers supports it

so in summary:
to access pointer(*) from a p2p(**) you need to use: *ptr and allocate that.
when you're using malloc please use casting cause it returns void*
ALWAYS free crap by yourself and don't trust anything, zombies can eat you even if they're in the pc memory:P

tip: i don't know if you know c++ but here's an approach that will help you:
think of your functions as constructors of the data you want so if you program in pure c, keep functions that build the object to the fullest and function that destroy the object and clear all the allocations and close files/pipes and what not. hope it helped you if not feel free to ask a follow up and i'll try to answer to the best of my abilities

Comment: Hey @LiorA Thank you for your awnser, and visualising your awnser in code.

Comment: My program works now. The code I posted wasn't the final program. Thanks for the tip on the casting with malloc, and I use the _crt derective when I'm building the program so spot memory leaks asap, I free everything manually when I know my program works. And another thank you for your last tip. I'm more fluent in C++ than I am in C, but I never thought about building functions as constructors for my datastructures/structures.

Comment: np glad i could help! about c++, it was all implemented using c so the basic idea is there, if u ever be interested in this there's a book called "object oriented in ANSI C" that shows how to implement it all (polymorphism, constructors and distructor and etc. :) )

Comment: Will pick that up! Thanks for the tip!